# How do I know if my wireless card is capable of packet injection?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, sniffing, packet-injection

I have this wireless card: http://www.edimax.com/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=8&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44  and I'm not sure if it supports packet injection.  How can I find this out?

Running OSX Leopard

Comment: As a first step you need to know what OS you are running.

Comment: Sorry, Mac OSX is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article below, the Edimax EW-7318USG does support packet injection:

[Injection Test Results: WUSB54Gv4, WT111v2, Edimax EW-7318USG, and Intel IPW2200](http://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=1689.msg8906)

Answer (score 1):

I may be completely wrong, but I was under the impression that to support injection your card needed a chipset with cracked or open source firmware.

Have a look at [this list](http://trac.kismac-ng.org/wiki/HardwareList) regarding kismac packet injection. It will hopefully tell you what chipset your card is using, and whether or not it will be suitable for injection.